# Sharing posts on facebook by blog id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share my individual blog posts from my websites blog onto facebook. Each post has a unique id as provided below, but the popup box is not changing the text content even tho the code is in unique divs with different id's, its just getting the first blog posts content.

This is what my blogs different id's use.

```
<? echo $blogitem_data['blogitem_id'] ?>
```

And the code I'm using

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Share <? echo $blogitem_data['blogitem_title'] ?> on facebook"onclick='postToFeed(); return false;' onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image9','','images/fb1a.png',1)"><img src="images/fb1.png" name="Image9" width="59" height="23" border="0"></a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx59", status: true, cookie: false});

      function postToFeed(response) {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri:'',
          link:'',
          picture: '',
          name: '- <? echo $blogitem_data['blogitem_title'] ?> ',
          caption: 'Welcome',
          description: '<? echo $string  ?> .'
        };

        function callback(response) {

        document.getElementById('divider-<? echo $blogitem_data['blogitem_id'] ?>').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The feed dialog is deprecated, better use the Share Button or the Share Dialog:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

You only need to add the URL as parameter, the Button/Dialog takes the necessary data directly from your website. Just make sure to include the necessary Open Graph Tags: http://ogp.me/

Comment: @luschin It doesn't go into how to get the content of individual posts with unique id's to grab the relevent content. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: not sure what's there to explain, indiviual posts have individual open graph tags.

Comment: Its just all my blog posts are in the same page. I want the share button on each post in the same page and not by individual pages with links like www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.mysite.com/singlepost.php?post_id=1964

Comment: you must have a specific link with correct open graph tags, that is the only way how it works. if you have everything on your page, just use the post_id as parameter and change the meta tags accordingly.

Comment: Fantastic, I will try this method and get back with a full answer to help out others. Thanks @luscin